# how to access http header fields of soap request of asmx web service using C#

Tags: c#, soap, http-headers, asmx

i want to read one specific field from HTTP header in .NET web application
i have tried the following but its not working

```
IncomingWebRequestContext request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
WebHeaderCollection headers = request.Headers;
string host = null;

if (headers["TraceId"] != null)
    host = headers["TraceId"];`
```

Comment: Do you get exception of what? What kind of exception if so?

Comment: i am getting this error
Invalid token '[' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: Which line of code shows the error. Looks like the error is somewhere else coz braces or square brackets are not closed properly

Comment: on starting brace of "TraceId"

Comment: Please include important new information you've been asked for in the comments by editing the original question instead of just posting it as a comment. That way others will have all relevant information in one place instead of having to dig through the comments.

Comment: Is your code part of a method? The exception suggests that the code is outside of a method declaration, sitting in the root of a class definition, for example.